# Jodatime - why is my dateTimeFormatter parseLocalDate always giving me 1 for month?

Tags: jodatime

I'm trying to parse a string to a date, but for some reason my month always comes out as 1...
Here's a failing test to show you what I mean:

```
@Test
public void shouldConvertStringToDate() {
    String date1 = "2012-06-28 23:01:54";
    DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
    LocalDate date = dateTimeFormatter.parseLocalDate(date1);
    Assert.assertEquals(2012, date.getYear());
    Assert.assertEquals(6, date.getMonthOfYear()); //actual is 1... ???
    Assert.assertEquals(28, date.getDayOfMonth());
}
```

Any idea what's going on??

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Days should be in lowercase `dd` not `DD`.
`D` - day of year
`d` - day of month
So your formatter should be

```
DateTimeFormat.forPattern("YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Comment: Cheers Ilya!! I was looking for something wrong with the month.... thanks so much!